# Is my implementation of the reCAPTCHA flawed?

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

I have this website [www.canuckssuck.org](http://www.canuckssuck.org) and starting this week I've been getting spam posts and comments. I've left the up there for your viewing pleasure. They always appear only on the first page. Is my implementation of the reCAPTCHA flawed or is it being legitimately defeated. Cut me some slack, this isn't meant to be a perfectly coded website. The entire site is only one page.

Here is my posts code:

```
# are we submitting the page?
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                  $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                  $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                  $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if ($resp->is_valid) {

                //validate data kind of!
                if($_POST['title'] == "")
                {
                    $_POST['title'] = "The Canucks Suck";
                }

                if($_POST['comment'] == "")
                {
                    $_POST['comment'] = "New Jersey is the best, we all know it!";
                }

                if($_POST['name'] == "")
                {
                    $_POST['name'] = "Anonymous";
                }
                if($_POST['location'] == "")
                {
                    $_POST['location'] = "Too embarrassed to disclose it.";
                }
                $ip = getUserIpAddr();

                $_POST['location'] = $_POST['location'] +"--"+ $ip;
                //convert line breaks to <br /> from /n etc
                $br_comment = nl2br($_POST['comment']);

                //add info to database
                $obj->insert_values("INSERT INTO posts (post_id, title, comment, name, time, location) VALUES (NULL, '$_POST[title]', '$br_comment', '$_POST[name]', NULL, '$_POST[location]')");

                header( 'Location: index.php?success=1' ) ;

                //for debugging
                echo "<h2 style=\"color:#00FF00; background:black; padding:2px;\">SUCCESSFULLY ADDED, THANKS!</h2>";

                } else {
                    echo "<span style=\"color:red;\">Sorry cannot add comment because you've failed to provide correct captcha! Try again...</span><br />";
                }
            }
            echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error);
?>
```

Comment: Unrelated to the reCAPTCHA discussion, if this code is what you have on your site, you are on a very good track of being attacked via SQL Injection and/or XSS.

Comment: You're so right... never did notice that. I don't think this is the source of my spam however. You would also have to succeed on the reCAPTACHA first. I'm in the process of switching this old site to Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reCapctcha may be compromised by services like [Death By Captcha](http://www.deathbycaptcha.com/user/login), which is basicly a place in India with a lot of "captcha solvers". Some of the spam bots may use it.

Just letting you know.

Comment: I guess this does answer my question. So even other forms of CAPTCHAS will be useless as well. I want to keep my site public so that anyone can post. Is there a better solution for this? Should I make my own series of a few questions? What do you suggest?